# Is more cores or more RAM better for mining?

Tags: mining

I'm trying to optimize CPU mining on a VPS. I'm wondering if you have any clue about this? Is it better to have more cores as RAM is not important (so just keep 1 RAM but not more), the other way around, or improve both with a ratio like 1 core 2 RAM?

Cheers

Comment: A VPS or dedicated server wouldn't be profitable. I would recommend nicehash if you want to try and mine without owning hardware

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Mining on a VPS is worthless because the CPU(s) are shared. Use a dedicated server.

Comment: Your comment make sense, but a dedicated server cost way more. Let's take OVH as an example, VPSs are almost 40 times cheaper (vps = 4€/month, dedi serv = 40€/week). Do you really believe dedicated servers are allowing to have such a better H/s rate?

Comment: But you'll never get any hashing power from a VPS so it's money down the drain.

Answer (score 1):

Each mining process/thread uses 2 MB memory. You want that to fit in cache for performance not to drop considerably. Each such process also requires AES-NI to have acceptable performance. So each mining process will want 2 MB cache and one core with AES-NI. Therefore, if you have more than twice as much megabytes of fast cache as cores with AES-NI, bump cores first. If less, bump cache first. If the same, bump both. Main RAM is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. However, during my research I never find any provider dealing about AES-NI or cache. I guess I'll have to create my own procedure for this

Comment: Each process does not require AES-NI. AES-NI is a processor (not process) feature and is not required for mining, but if the processor has that feature it will speed up your mining. You can get "acceptable" performance without AES-NI.

The biggest bottleneck is the 2MB scratchpad. That needs to be in the L3 cache or your mining is severely negatively impacted. On a VPS you are sharing the L3 cache with every other VPS so you are highly unlikely to get enough cache for even a single thread.

Bottom line - you are never going to be profitable renting a VPS for mining XMR.